How to only evaluate this function in the new variables after the derivative has been taken?
I have the following situation. I will first post the code and then explain what I'm trying to do and what is going wrong
F[1,2] = Function[{x,y}, x^2 E[1] + y^2 E[2]];

coords = {x,y};
coeff[i_][a_, b_][x_,y_] := Coefficient[F[a, b][x,y], E[i]];
derF[a_, b_][x_,y_] := Table[D[coeff[i][a, b][x,y], coords[[j]]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]

The idea is this: I'm defining some collection of functions of $(x,y)$ that I'm defining as F[a,b]. Each of the functions is a linear combination of the variables E[1] and E[2].
When I define coeff[i][a,b] I want to extract the function that appears as the coefficient of E[i] in F[a,b]. Then I want to define a matrix of functions derF[a,b] that contains the derivatives of the coefficients of E[1] and E[2] appearing in F[a,b].
My problem is that I want derF[a,b] to be a function in the sense that I can put whatever variable as argument. So for example, I would like to be able to use derF[a,b][t,s] and get the matrix with the functions as functions of $(t,s)$.
The problem is that if I use this code and compute derF[a,b][t,s] I get zero. And I do understand why: Mathematica is basically taking the derivative of a function of $(t,s)$ with respect to $(x,y)$. That's not what I want. I want it to first evaluate the derivative and then substitute the variable, but I have no idea how to achieve this.
So, how do I fix this code to achieve the right intent?

So, the E[i] are always either E[1] or E[2]?

You have an expression like this F[a, b][x, y], but you've only defined F with F[1,2]. Does that mean a and b will always be 1 or 2? Or is that your actual question--how to define F for any a and b?

I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you're saying. It seems to me that you either want f1 = Function[{x, y}, x^2 e[1] + y^2 e[2]] or f2[a_, b_] := Function[{x, y}, x^2 e[a] + y^2 e[b]]. Maybe you can give a concrete example of what you expect for f[a,b] for some specific a and b. And then what you expect for coeff[i][a,b][x,y] for some specific i, a, and b.

Also, just a nit, but E is a pre-defined symbol, so you may want to avoid it.

Hi @lericr, sorry, I should have used e[i] instead. It is always just either e[1] or e[2]. Now, I don't have a general formula for F[a,b] as a function of a and b. I have manually defined F[a, b] for a = 1,2,3 and b=1,2,3, but here I just put one of them as an example. The point is that I have a $3\times 3$ matrix of functions of {x,y} which are linear combinations of the symbols e[1] and e[2]

Oh, so everything works okay when you pass in x and y, just not other arguments like t and s, is that it?

Yeah, you're sort of hard-coding everything to x and y. Don't do that. :)

Yes, exactly! Everything works with x and y but when I change the argument it doesn't. I understood why (I hard-coded x and y in the coords list), but don't know the best work-around

My first thought is to use Derivative instead of D

Okay, sorry for not having an actual answer to post yet, but I think we need to first decide whether you want to operate with polynomial expressions or with functions (functions in the sense of Function[...]. You keep referring to x and y in your code, which implies you like using those as indeterminates (formal variables), but then at the end you want to get expressions using other variables, e.g. t and s. If your end goal is to be able to use any arbitrary symbols/inputs, then probably we should lean toward using just pure Functions.

Basically, in this expression D[coeff[i][a, b][x, y], coords[[j]]], when you pass in t and s to derF[a, b][t, s] you're going to end up taking the derivative with respect to a variable that doesn't exist in the expression your taking the derivate of.

So, you either need to do everything with x and y and the do a replacement {x->t, y->s} or you could just do all the work with pure Functions and just use Derivative on the resulting pure function. You might even want to skip taking the coefficient and just do Derivative[1,0] or Derivative[0,1] depending on what i was passed in. Not sure if that's exactly the semantic you want, but that feels like what you're trying to do to me.

If you would explain what result you expect to get, people will provide far smarter solutions.

@TedErsek: I will write in plain math then. Imagine that you have some collection of functions $F_{AB}(x,y)$ that takes values in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to construct the matrix of derivatives $\partial_i [F_{AB}]j$. I coded the functions $F{AB}(x,y)$ as linear combinations of symbols e[i] that play the role of the basis vectors. So I wanted to extract the coefficient and differentiate. But I want the final result to be again a function, so that I can use whatever argument I want. The problem is that to take the derivatives I'm using that coords list...

@lericr I think that it is probably better to work all the time with Function, I'll try to recast the code using that, because I feel it might be a better solution in the end.

First of all E is the transcendental number 2.71828 ... Second problem is that you defined F[1,2] but not F[a,b]. Third problem is that even if your definition for F[__] would have been used, it was defined to return a Function, but you need it to return an algebraic expression because that is what Coefficient needs. This might be wanted to define:
Clear[F];
F[m_, n_] := x^2 e[m] + y^2 e[n];

See what you get from F[a,b] then. I could have used F[a_,b_] instead of F[m_,n_], but the version above better illustrates how this works.
Or you might have wanted to define this:
Clear[F];
F[x_,y_]:=x^2 e[1]+y^2 e[2];

See what you get from F[a,b] in that case.
Also instead of e[1], e[2] you could use (e1, e2) or (E1, E2).
That will get you closer to code that does what you want.
Tip: Develop your code one step at a time and ensure each step does what you intend before taking on the next step.

Thanks @TedErsek. I'm sorry but I was unclear in my question. The point is that for each {a,b} I have a function F[a,b][x,y]. I don't have a general formula that specifies these functions in terms of {a,b}, I only know how to list them individually. In the question I just posted one, namely, F[1,2], but in principle I'd like {a,b} to have values from 1 to 3 for example.

I don't really like this, but here's a hack to hopefully get your desired end result. Keep all your other definitions, but change derF like this:
derF[a_, b_][x_, y_] := 
  Table[D[coeff[i][a, b][x, y], {x, y}[[j]]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]

Per my comment, I would personally prefer to come up with a better abstraction.

I think this is an approach to what you want. I might have made some wrong turns, but I hope it's enough for you to untangle if necessary.
First step: Let's take both derivatives for all of your Fs (we're keeping everything as pure functions).
matrixOfDerivativeFunctions = 
  Transpose[Outer[Construct, Derivative @@@ IdentityMatrix[2], F @@@ Tuples[Range[3], 2]]]
(* {{Derivative[1, 0][F[1, 1]], Derivative[0, 1][F[1, 1]]},
    {Derivative[1, 0][F[1, 2]], Derivative[0, 1][F[1, 2]]}, 
    {Derivative[1, 0][F[1, 3]], Derivative[0, 1][F[1, 3]]}, 
    {Derivative[1, 0][F[2, 1]], Derivative[0, 1][F[2, 1]]},
    {Derivative[1, 0][F[2, 2]], Derivative[0, 1][F[2, 2]]},
    {Derivative[1, 0][F[2, 3]], Derivative[0, 1][F[2, 3]]},
    {Derivative[1, 0][F[3, 1]], Derivative[0, 1][F[3, 1]]},
    {Derivative[1, 0][F[3, 2]], Derivative[0, 1][F[3, 2]]},
    {Derivative[1, 0][F[3, 3]], Derivative[0, 1][F[3, 3]]}} *)

If that looks confusing, just work your way inside out. You said that you had F[n,m] defined for n,m = 1, 2, 3, so that's where the F @@@ Tuples[Range[3], 2] comes from. The transpose is just because I just assumed that's how you want it organized.
Okay, we have a bunch of functions. Let's apply them to some variables, say s and t.
allLinearCombos = Map[Construct[#, s, t] &, matrixOfDerivativeFunctions, {2}]

I won't keep posting the output, because it's tedious and your Fs will be defined already so you should hopefully be getting simpler outputs. Also, I'm just working with abstract, undefined F, so if there are errors here, it might be because of something I didn't take into account with regard to your Fs.
At this point, it seems like you want the coefficients of the "bases", e[1] and e[2].
Outer[Coefficient, allLinearCombos, {e[1], e[2]}]

Note that I'm assuming lowercase e not E.
Of course, you can bundle all this up into a function that gives just the "mini-matrix" for a single F that you had originally.
newDerF[a_, b_][x_, y_] :=
  Outer[
    Coefficient, 
    Map[Construct[#, x, y] &, Through[(Derivative @@@ IdentityMatrix[2])[F[a, b]]]], 
    {e[1], e[2]}]

